# What user is using all of our CPU?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, cpu, plesk

This weekend we get this message from our Server hosting. Now we need to know what user/website is using all of our CPU. This because we need to know how to end this. Can anybody help ous please?

This is the report we get from the hosting company(some words are in dutch, our language):

> Parameter serverstatus "Diensten > Geheugengebruik Apache" is gewijzigd van "yellow" naar "red".
>
> top - 07:27:34 up 8:59, 0 users, load average: 38.91, 30.99, 45.23
>   Tasks: 141 total, 53 running, 88 sleeping, 0 stopped, 0 zombie
>   Cpu(s): 84.1%us, 9.8%sy, 0.0%ni, 1.5%id, 0.0%wa, 0.0%hi, 0.0%si, 4.6%st
>   Mem: 2097152k total, 1694040k used, 403112k free, 0k buffers
>   Swap: 0k total, 0k used, 0k free, 58708k cached
>
> PID USER PR NI VIRT RES SHR S %CPU %MEM TIME+ COMMAND
>   23963 www-data 20 0 93484 47m 4228 R 2.4 2.3 0:12.32 apache2
>   23619 www-data 20 0 89132 44m 5288 R 1.6 2.2 0:23.02 apache2
>   23647 www-data 20 0 97064 51m 4932 R 1.6 2.5 0:26.43 apache2
>   23787 www-data 20 0 95132 50m 5248 R 1.6 2.5 0:22.06 apache2
>   23797 www-data 20 0 89284 43m 4216 R 1.6 2.1 0:09.87 apache2
>   24179 www-data 20 0 95720 49m 4200 R 1.6 2.4 0:05.06 apache2
>   24181 www-data 20 0 96128 49m 4160 R 1.6 2.4 0:05.37 apache2
>   24197 www-data 20 0 95636 49m 4160 R 1.6 2.4 0:04.15 apache2
>   24201 www-data 20 0 95360 49m 4160 R 1.6 2.4 0:04.03 apache2
>   24223 www-data 20 0 90928 45m 4112 R 1.6 2.2 0:03.59 apache2
>   24235 www-data 20 0 90416 44m 4160 R 1.6 2.2 0:03.27 apache2
>   24244 www-data 20 0 96936 50m 3960 R 1.6 2.5 0:03.17 apache2
>   3972 root 20 0 87684 16m 684 S 0.8 0.8 7:25.02 sw-collectd
>   23732 www-data 20 0 91788 46m 4208 R 0.8 2.3 0:11.88 apache2
>   23756 www-data 20 0 96440 51m 5008 R 0.8 2.5 0:23.19 apache2
>   23789 www-data 20 0 95688 49m 4228 R 0.8 2.4 0:16.11 apache2
>   23796 www-data 20 0 90756 45m 4956 R 0.8 2.2 0:17.88 apache2
>   23952 www-data 20 0 92948 48m 5288 R 0.8 2.4 0:09.78 apache2
>   23961 www-data 20 0 86716 42m 5104 R 0.8 2.1 0:12.64 apache2
>   24188 www-data 20 0 90480 45m 4212 R 0.8 2.2 0:04.57 apache2
>   24194 www-data 20 0 79376 34m 4932 R 0.8 1.7 0:04.37 apache2
>   24196 www-data 20 0 90816 45m 4240 R 0.8 2.2 0:04.33 apache2
>   24199 www-data 20 0 93444 47m 4160 R 0.8 2.3 0:03.45 apache2
>   24200 www-data 20 0 96936 50m 4156 R 0.8 2.5 0:04.14 apache2
>   24202 www-data 20 0 88488 43m 4164 R 0.8 2.1 0:04.01 apache2
>   24216 www-data 20 0 95108 49m 4160 R 0.8 2.4 0:03.85 apache2
>   24220 www-data 20 0 89044 43m 4212 R 0.8 2.1 0:03.52 apache2
>   24221 www-data 20 0 95900 49m 4200 R 0.8 2.4 0:03.11 apache2
>   24224 www-data 20 0 88524 42m 4120 R 0.8 2.1 0:02.91 apache2
>   24229 www-data 20 0 95612 50m 4928 R 0.8 2.5 0:03.42 apache2
>   24236 www-data 20 0 88732 43m 4160 R 0.8 2.1 0:03.27 apache2
>   24239 www-data 20 0 95844 49m 4136 R 0.8 2.4 0:02.65 apache2
>   24242 www-data 20 0 95896 50m 4172 R 0.8 2.4 0:02.64 apache2
>   24245 www-data 20 0 95844 49m 4132 R 0.8 2.4 0:02.31 apache2
>   24248 www-data 20 0 95820 49m 4124 R 0.8 2.4 0:02.52 apache2
>   24251 www-data 20 0 96952 50m 3960 R 0.8 2.5 0:02.76 apache2
>   24257 www-data 20 0 89788 44m 4152 R 0.8 2.2 0:02.11 apache2
>   24286 www-data 20 0 92188 47m 4888 R 0.8 2.3 0:02.04 apache2
>   24298 www-data 20 0 95828 49m 3956 R 0.8 2.4 0:02.30 apache2
>   24349 www-data 20 0 79356 33m 3964 R 0.8 1.6 0:00.81 apache2
>   24351 root 20 0 10368 8984 1736 R 0.8 0.4 0:00.70 awstats.pl
>   24359 www-data 20 0 78144 31m 3512 R 0.8 1.5 0:00.31 apache2
>   24361 www-data 20 0 64536 18m 3136 R 0.8 0.9 0:00.07 apache2
>   24362 www-data 20 0 72860 26m 3364 R 0.8 1.3 0:00.19 apache2
>   24364 www-data 20 0 72864 26m 3292 R 0.8 1.3 0:00.19 apache2
>   24366 www-data 20 0 69200 22m 3404 R 0.8 1.1 0:00.12 apache2
>   24368 www-data 20 0 63548 16m 2732 R 0.8 0.8 0:00.01 apache2
>   24369 www-data 20 0 68416 21m 3380 R 0.8 1.1 0:00.10 apache2
>   1 root 20 0 2504 656 496 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.04 init
>   2 root 20 0 0 0 0 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 kthreadd/160422
>   3 root 20 0 0 0 0 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 khelper/1604223
>   4 root 20 0 0 0 0 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 rpciod/1604223/
>   5 root 20 0 0 0 0 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 rpciod/1604223/
>   6 root 20 0 0 0 0 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 rpciod/1604223/
>   7 root 20 0 0 0 0 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 rpciod/1604223/
>   8 root 20 0 0 0 0 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 nfsiod/1604223
>   174 root 20 0 2336 292 200 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.32 cron
>   238 syslog 20 0 1948 280 204 S 0.0 0.0 0:09.10 syslogd
>   252 mysql 20 0 178m 28m 3448 S 0.0 1.4 2:27.55 mysqld
>   284 root 20 0 5504 400 396 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 sshd
>   301 bind 20 0 49944 908 344 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.07 named
>   320 root 20 0 3324 220 148 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 couriertcpd
>   322 root 20 0 1720 412 344 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 courierlogger
>   331 root 20 0 3324 220 148 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 couriertcpd
>   334 root 20 0 1720 412 344 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 courierlogger
>   341 root 20 0 3324 24 20 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 couriertcpd
>   344 root 20 0 1588 8 4 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 courierlogger
>   351 root 20 0 3324 112 64 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 couriertcpd
>   354 root 20 0 1720 240 184 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 courierlogger
>   3214 root 20 0 5780 576 468 S 0.0 0.0 0:10.70 master
>   3223 postfix 20 0 6576 1680 736 S 0.0 0.1 0:32.16 qmgr
>   3231 root 20 0 2456 256 200 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 xinetd
>   3249 postfix 20 0 6352 1460 1132 S 0.0 0.1 0:03.25 tlsmgr
>   3263 bind 20 0 49076 676 344 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.05 named
>   3280 root 20 0 32164 3380 508 S 0.0 0.2 0:08.69 spamd
>   3307 popuser 20 0 32164 2864 372 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.03 spamd
>   3369 postfix 20 0 64036 1216 896 S 0.0 0.1 0:01.86 psa-pc-remote
>   3425 root 20 0 62476 16m 3652 S 0.0 0.8 0:13.64 apache2
>   3426 www-data 20 0 35772 9700 156 S 0.0 0.5 0:00.49 apache2
>   3478 sw-cp-se 20 0 4492 580 56 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 sw-cp-serverd
>   3908 root 20 0 65400 19m 2576 S 0.0 0.9 0:06.86 sw-engine
>   3999 zabbix 25 5 7112 564 168 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 zabbix_agentd
>   4001 zabbix 25 5 7112 788 392 S 0.0 0.0 0:07.83 zabbix_agentd
>   4003 zabbix 25 5 7112 524 124 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 zabbix_agentd
>   4004 zabbix 25 5 7112 524 124 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 zabbix_agentd
>   4005 zabbix 25 5 7112 524 124 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 zabbix_agentd
>   4008 zabbix 25 5 7112 524 124 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 zabbix_agentd
>   4009 zabbix 25 5 7112 524 124 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 zabbix_agentd
>   4010 zabbix 25 5 7124 720 304 S 0.0 0.0 0:01.40 zabbix_agentd
>   16888 root 20 0 6256 1252 812 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.00 cron
>   16893 root 20 0 1792 464 396 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 sh
>   16897 root 20 0 1716 416 340 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 run-parts
>   16898 root 20 0 1792 464 400 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 50plesk-daily
>   16899 root 20 0 73892 27m 3460 S 0.0 1.3 0:01.04 sw-engine
>   17693 root 20 0 1792 456 392 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 sh
>   17694 root 20 0 56636 11m 3256 S 0.0 0.5 0:01.14 sw-engine
>   17697 root 20 0 1792 464 396 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 sh
>   17698 root 20 0 12008 2616 1728 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.99 statistics_coll
>   23885 postfix 20 0 6196 2588 1920 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.04 cleanup
>   23886 postfix 20 0 6856 3116 1712 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.01 trivial-rewrite
>   23942 postfix 20 0 5820 1720 1368 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.03 bounce
>   23987 postfix 20 0 6220 3004 2304 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.35 smtp
>   24016 postfix 20 0 6220 2992 2308 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.20 smtp
>   24159 root 20 0 1792 504 436 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 sh
>   24160 root 20 0 4308 2704 1640 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.03 awstats_buildst
>   24234 www-data 20 0 89108 43m 4200 S 0.0 2.1 0:03.22 apache2
>   24247 www-data 20 0 90672 44m 4112 S 0.0 2.2 0:02.79 apache2
>   24254 www-data 20 0 96516 50m 4008 R 0.0 2.4 0:02.72 apache2
>   24260 postfix 20 0 6220 2992 2304 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.15 smtp
>   24261 postfix 20 0 6220 3000 2304 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.16 smtp
>   24262 postfix 20 0 6220 2988 2304 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.13 smtp
>   24263 postfix 20 0 5796 1744 1384 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.00 pickup
>   24264 postfix 20 0 6220 2984 2304 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.13 smtp
>   24265 postfix 20 0 5792 1752 1324 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.00 scache
>   24273 postfix 20 0 6220 2988 2304 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.09 smtp
>   24275 postfix 20 0 6220 2980 2304 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.11 smtp
>   24276 postfix 20 0 6220 2980 2304 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.08 smtp
>   24279 postfix 20 0 6220 2984 2304 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.08 smtp
>   24282 postfix 20 0 6220 2984 2300 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.05 smtp
>   24283 postfix 20 0 5820 1720 1368 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.02 bounce
>   24285 postfix 20 0 6220 2984 2304 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.05 smtp
>   24288 postfix 20 0 6220 2968 2304 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.02 smtp
>   24297 postfix 20 0 5820 1716 1368 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.01 bounce
>   24300 postfix 20 0 5820 1716 1368 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.00 bounce
>   24305 postfix 20 0 5820 1720 1368 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.00 bounce
>   24308 postfix 20 0 5820 1712 1368 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.00 bounce
>   24315 postfix 20 0 5820 1712 1368 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.00 bounce
>   24318 postfix 20 0 5820 1720 1368 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.00 bounce
>   24322 postfix 20 0 5820 1716 1368 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.00 bounce
>   24325 postfix 20 0 5820 1716 1368 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.00 bounce
>   24328 postfix 20 0 5820 1712 1368 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.00 bounce
>   24330 postfix 20 0 5820 1716 1368 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.00 bounce
>   24334 www-data 20 0 95828 49m 3952 R 0.0 2.4 0:01.82 apache2
>   24350 root 20 0 1792 492 428 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 sh
>   24372 www-data 20 0 64264 17m 2776 R 0.0 0.8 0:00.01 apache2
>   24375 www-data 20 0 62476 14m 864 S 0.0 0.7 0:00.00 apache2
>   24379 root 20 0 1792 484 420 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 sh
>   24380 root 20 0 2504 1044 768 R 0.0 0.0 0:00.01 top
>   24381 www-data 20 0 62476 14m 852 S 0.0 0.7 0:00.00 apache2
>   24382 root 20 0 62476 13m 0 R 0.0 0.6 0:00.00 apache2
>   24383 root 20 0 62476 13m 0 R 0.0 0.6 0:00.00 apache2

Comment: check "TIME" colon in `ps afvvx` output

Answer (score 0):

Since the top running process is apache2 you should check apache logs and see which website is being more used/accessed.